# R Shiny add interspersed text in grid.arrange function

Tags: r, shiny

In a R Shiny App, inside a Box component I'm rendering 4 plots with this code:

```
grid.arrange(p1,p3,p2,p4,nrow=2, ncol=2)
```

How can I add a text interspersed in the plots to get something like the image:

[image]

Comment: you can create the Some text as a tesxtGrob, the add that to the grid.arrange?

Comment: Cannot use it as the library(grid) is not part of CRAN and for special reasons I'm trying to stick to CRAN supporte libraries due to deployment issues

Comment: `grid` is not included on CRAN because it's installed as one of the base packages automatically when you install R. You should be able to call `library(grid)` on any R instance without installing anything additional.